# selenium Не удается найти указанный файл

Tags: python, selenium

Начал изучать библиотеку selenium для python3 и столкнулся с проблемой.

```
>>>from selenium import webdriver
>>>driver=webdriver.Firefox()
Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x01B6FBD0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Defernus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 163, in __del__
    self.stop()
  File "C:\Users\Defernus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 135, in stop
    if self.process is None:
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Defernus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 64, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "C:\Users\Defernus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Defernus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Defernus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 135, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\Defernus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Весь день убил, а так и не понял, как решить.

Comment: Сообщение "AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" довольно прозрачное. Из него и исходите при поиске ошибки.

Comment: *"Не удается найти указанный файл"* и *"geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH"* сообщения об ошибке намекают, что `geckodriver` не найден—есть ли у вас на машине `geckodriver.exe` и находится ли его папка в `%PATH%`?

Comment: geckodriver в PATH есть.

Comment: @Defernus с `.exe` на конце? Попробуйте запустить команду `subprocess.Popen()` как она указана в service.py на 64 строке.

Answer (score 2):

```
driver=webdriver.Firefox('напиши сюда полный путь до geckodriver')
```

ссылка на скачивание geckodriver: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Была такая же проблема решил таким способом

Comment: А еще можно (и более правильно) добавить все в PATH/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по ошибке - `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`

Необходимо geckodriver добавить в переменную PATH